# Connect Excel VBA to Microsoft Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: vba, excel, azure, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to connect to Azure Data Warehouse using Excel VBA ? If so, could someone please share the connection string that has to be used ?

I have been using this connection string to connect to SQL server and this doesn't work with Azure ,

```
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=INSTANCE\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-connect-overview#supported-drivers-and-connection-strings

Answer (score 2):

This is the connectionstring that worked for me,

```
"Provider=SQLNCLI11;Password=MYPASSWORD;User ID=MYUSERID; " & _
"Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE; " & _
"Data Source=tcp:MYSERVERNAME.database.windows.net;"
```

Comment: ...was having similar problems...I Assume SQLNCLI11 is for SQL Native Client library 11? I did get it working with your connection string but wondering why version 12 doesn't work...i.e. SQLNCLI12